# Can you receive the Foehammer Achievement in a dishonoured save and if you force exit the game before your party dies?

Tags: achievements, baldurs-gate-3

When you complete the game in the new Honour mode, you can get the Foehammer achievement. In my game my party died. If you die, you can delete the save file, or play it in some "Dishonoured" mode.

My questions are:

- When you continue your dishonoured game, can you still receive the Foehammer achievement? In the settings the Honour mode option is still checked.
- Will the achievement still trigger when you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> before your entire party dies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- No. Dishonoured mode is basically a custom mode. Your game will simply no longer be in Honour mode, invalidating the *Foehammer* achievement progress. (See the Patch #5 notes [here](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1086940/view/3897365207669541523).)
- The game will save even when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>ing out, so that will only make it harder to survive a specifically perilous situation.
  A way to bypass this (at the moment) is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and quit the executable using the Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>). Restarting the game will allow you to load your last save file, and your playthrough should still qualify for the *Foehammer* achievement.

Comment: You can probably also make a safety copy of the save-file which you can recover if you fail to try again. - But if you do this, you can probably also just use other cheats/trainers/tools to work around the honor-mode to get the achievement.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+Shift+ESC will immediately open Task Manager (compared to Ctrl+Alt+Delete which will open a menu containing other options first)

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for pointing that out :)